# Successfully adding routes in an Ubuntu Server 12.04

Tags: routing, linux-networking, ubuntu-12.04

I have a virtual machine on top of VMware on which I run Ubuntu Server 12.04. I have two network adapters configured for the virtual machine and my /etc/network/interfaces configuration looks like this:

```
# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
address 10.226.83.2
netmask 255.255.255.248
gateway 10.226.83.1

# Management Interface
auto eth1
iface eth1 inet static
address 10.20.9.200
netmask 255.255.240.0
up ip route add 10.20.0.0/20 via 10.20.0.1 dev eth1 || true
up ip route add 10.21.120.0/22 via 10.20.0.1 dev eth1 || true
up ip route add 10.13.122.0/22 via 10.20.0.1 dev eth1 || true
```

My problem is that with this specific configuration I am unable to see the route to 10.13.122.0/22 when calling route:

```
$ route
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use     Iface
default         10.226.83.1     0.0.0.0         UG    100    0        0 eth0
10.20.0.0       *               255.255.240.0   U     0      0        0 eth1
10.21.120.0     10.20.0.1       255.255.252.0   UG    0      0        0 eth1
10.118.233.0    10.118.233.2    255.255.255.0   UG    0      0        0 tun10000
10.118.233.2    *               255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 tun10000
10.226.83.0     *               255.255.255.248 U     0      0        0 eth0
```

What I am trying to accomplish is that traffic to and from the networks 10.20.0.0/20, 10.21.120.0/22, and 10.13.122.0/22 would traverse through eth1 towards 10.20.0.1, and otherwise traffic would go through eth0 and via 10.226.83.1. tun10000 is an adapter generated by our OpenVPN confiuration and that can be ignored in this case.

Currently everything except for 10.13.122.0/22 is working fine, which is reflected in the routing table; I cannot see 10.13.122.0/22 in the table even though the route for it was added using the same syntax as for the other two networks.

Also, when I do sudo /etc/init.d/networking restart I get the following:

```
$ sudo /etc/init.d/networking restart
 * Running /etc/init.d/networking restart is deprecated because it may not enable again some interfaces
 * Reconfiguring network interfaces...
                                                    ssh stop/waiting
ssh start/running, process 21240
RTNETLINK answers: File exists
RTNETLINK answers: Invalid argument
ssh stop/waiting
ssh start/running, process 21306
```

Even with the two RTNETLINK answers I am getting a functional interface except for the route to 10.13.122.0/22. How can I get this route to work and is there a way I would get rid of the "File exists" and "Invalid argument" messages?

Comment: Don't use the old `route` command; use `ip route show` (or `ip ro sh` for short).

Comment: Just curious: How do you reach `10.20.0.1`?

Comment: @gf_ I am just guessing here since obviously this is not my comfort zone: I presumed that I am able to reach it since I am routing 10.20.0.0/20 via eth1.

Comment: @treiman: Are you able to reach `10.20.0.1` actually, for example via ping?

Comment: @gf_: Yes I am, without any problems.

Answer (score 1):

`10.21.120.0/22` is 10.21.120.0-10.21.123.255, hence is identical to `10.13.122.0/22`. So setting a route for `10.13.122.0/22` will give the error "File exists" (or more correctly "entry already exists").

You need to figure out your network topology a bit better.

Comment: Your answer made me realize I had the wrong mask in the configuration; swapping 10.13.122.0/22 to 10.13.122.0/23 got things working. However I am still seeing "RTNETLINK answers: File exists", which leads me to the following question:

How could there still be overlap if 10.21.120.0/22 is 10.21.120.1 - 10.21.123.254 usable and 10.13.122.0/23 is 10.13.122.1 - 10.13.123.254 usable?

Comment: Haven't you answered your own question? 10.13.122.1 - 10.13.123.254 is contained in 10.21.120.1 - 10.21.123.254. You probably also need to change 10.21.120.0/22 to 10.21.120.0/23.

Answer (score 0):

I had the wrong mask in the configuration; swapping 10.13.122.0/22 to 10.13.122.0/23 got things working.